# Cyclomatic-complexity metrics

Tags: java

I am wondering if using LOC and cyclomatic-complexity metrics can anyone draw any conclusions about the relative complexity of the two codes below? is kinda doing my head in.

Code A

```
 int i = 1;
    while(i < = 5){

    playACard(i);

    if (playerHasWon(i))
    break;
    i++
    }
```

Code B

```
int j = 0;

int i = 2;

j = i;
j = j + i;

j++;
System.out.println (j);

System.out.println
```

Comment: Neither snippet is valid in either C++ or Java.

Comment: Is this php or what? im confused im not a programmer, but dont close it please. i thought this was a website for helping others

Comment: Well, yes and no. You may want to read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And if you're not a programmer, why do you care about cyclomatic complexity metrics?

Comment: It is Java... the only "invalid" line is: System.out.println

Comment: because i want to learn? thomas you are quite rude arent you

Comment: @d'alar'cop: And `i++`. Even if it had the semicolon, unreachable code is an error in Java.

Comment: @Thomas - i++ is not unreachable... the break occurs on the first line of an un-bracketted if... so i++ runs on each iteration- break only occurs if the 'if' condition is satisfied. And I would say the absent semi-colon is a type. Also the general look is obviously Java.

Comment: I am merely stating facts. I'm sorry if that came across as rude; that was not intended. And although this is technically a question with a single, well-defined answer, the answer is not likely to be of any use because the question is fairly meaningless.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Ah, you're right, the broken indentation messed with my head.

Comment: @Thomas I disagree about the question being meaningless or the answer being useless. It is just a simple illustration of cyclomatic complexity measures. Yes the indentation is no good!

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Yet he asked for the _relative_ complexity of two code snippets, which really is comparing apples to oranges. Stephen C put this very well.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, understood.

Comment: Hola Jose, seria bueno si podrias darle un 'tick' a uno de las respuestas si te sirvio algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using advanced LOC tools (i.e. my eyes and fingers :-) ) I calculate the LOC counts for the two pieces of code are the same ... ignoring blank lines.

For a cyclometric complexity count, you need parseable source code ... in some programming language ... for tools to work.  I defer to @d'alar'cop 's answer for a hand calculation  and the explanation of how he arrived at it.

---

But to be honest, LOC and Cyclometric Complexity measures for code like this is not helpful.  The two samples do completely different things, so it really makes little difference which is more "complex".

To my mind, CC is only really useful for identifying excessively complex code in a first-pass review of a codebase.  Once you've identified the problem *areas*, an experienced programmer is a better judge of real complexity (i.e. the kind of stuff that makes the code hard to understand) ... and whether that complexity is necessary / inherent in the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Code B has cyclomatic complexity of 1.
There is *only* 1 possible path through the code.

Cyclomatic complexity measures the number of possible paths of execution (this is useful in testing and size estimations of a software system.) - but most people would say it's not accurate or useful for the latter.

Code A has cyclomatic complexity of 4. As the code can either enter the loop or not enter it (same as leaving it) (2 possible paths) and there is one 'if statement' which multiplies the possibilities by 2 again.

Cheers.

Any more explanation required?

Comment: can you please give an explanation, this would really help

Comment: done... let me know if it's not clear